# Any builtin C/C++ library functions to encode domain names to DHCP option code 119 domain-search list?

Tags: c, c++11, dhcp

Any builtin C/C++ library functions to encode domain names to DHCP option code 119 domain-search list

Example:
I want to convert "google.com" to "0x06'google'0x03'com'0x00"

Any sample optimised programs would help too.

Comment: no standard functions.

Comment: Doesn't seem particular hard to implement?  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3397

Comment: networking doesn't exist in any C or C++ standards. It's the OS-specific code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example implementation:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void compress(char **data, size_t *data_len, const char *domain) {
    char *tmp = realloc(*data, *data_len + 1 + strlen(domain) + 1);
    if(!tmp) {
        printf("realloc failed\n");
        return;
    }
    *data = tmp;
    size_t old_data_len = *data_len;
    for(size_t j = 0;;) {
        const char *sep = strchr(domain + j, '.');
        size_t len = sep ? sep - domain - j : strlen(domain + j);
        if(len > 255) {
            printf("TBD: long labels\n");
            return;
        }
        (*data)[*data_len] = len;
        strncpy(*data + *data_len + 1, domain + j, len);
        j += len + 1;
        *data_len += 1 + len;
        if(!sep) {
            (*data)[(*data_len)++] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    // Can we compress the string by using a pointer?
    for(size_t j = old_data_len; j < *data_len; ) {
        char *p = memmem(*data, old_data_len, *data + j, *data_len - j);
        if(p) {
            if(*data - p > 0x3f) {
                printf("overflow\n");
                return;
            }
            (*data)[j] = 0xc0 | (*data - p);
            *data_len = j + 1;
            char *tmp = realloc(*data, *data_len);
            if(!tmp) {
                printf("realloc failed\n");
                return;
            }
            *data = tmp;
            break;
        }
        j += 1 + (*data)[j];
    }
}


int main() {
    char *data = NULL;
    size_t data_len = 0;
    compress(&data, &data_len, "example.com");
    compress(&data, &data_len, "www.example.com");
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, data, data_len);
    free(data);
}
```

and the result is:

```
$ ./a.out | od -c
0000000  \a   e   x   a   m   p   l   e 003   c   o   m  \0 003   w   w
0000020   w 300
0000022
```

You could optimize this by having caller allocate a sufficient amount of memory (stack or heap) then if heap `realloc` when compress is done.  I have not measured it but it's possible searching for the pointer is faster by looking at each successive labels in reverse. You would probably need a size_t[] with a length of each net string to do so.  The benefit is that no match returns with a single call to `memmem()` instead of 3ish.

For DHCP, you split the data into blocks of option_length and prefix each block with two bytes { 119, option_length }.

Comment: Done with accepting answer. My upvote is not considered looks like.

Comment: @Sravani Great.  You will be able to upvote when you get more reputation.